# How to get avatar for unassigned (avatar with question mark) in JIRA

Tags: jira-plugin, avatar

I'm developing a plugin for JIRA. The plugin lists issues with details like assigned user, priority etc. In my velocity template file, I've the following statement to get the avatar for assigned User

...
${avatarService.getAvatarAbsoluteURL(${user},${user.getName()}, $Avatar.Size.SMALL)}
...

However, if the issue is unassigned the avatar of admin is shown. But when I open the issue to see the details. JIRA shows the assigned user as "Unassigned" and avatar with questiion mark is shown correctly.
Please help in solving this.

Thanks in advance,

Shashi